# Dynamically pass entries to Method requiring params

Tags: c#, iterator, parameters

I'm currently having the following method which requires params - I cannot change this methods definition:

```
public static DoStuff(params Parameter[] p){ /* ... */ }
```

I do not know how many parameters I'll have at runtime, so I want to pass an array or a list - I've thought about using Iterators like this:

```
List<Parameter> pList = new List<Parameter>();
pList.Add(new Parameter("@a", "aaaa!");
pList.Add(new Parameter("@b", "bbbb!");
pList.Add(new Parameter("@c", "cccc!");
DoStuff(Iterate(pList));
```

And here's the Iterate-Method:

```
public static IEnumerator<Parameter> Iterate(List<Parameter> pList)
    {
        foreach (Parameter p in pList)
            yield return p;
    }
```

Unfortunately, it does not work, it keeps telling me that it can't cast (generated type) to CommandParameter.

Any help (or different approaches) would be appreciated!

**Edit:** It appears, in an attempt to simplify my solution for the sake of making my question understandable I trivialized my problem.

In addition to this array, I'd like to also pass "normal" Parameters like this:

```
DoStuff(Iterate(pList), new Parameter("@d", "dddd!"));
```

I do this merely out of curiosity to see whether it works - but this does not work simply by casting my `List` to an `Array` and appending the next Parameter.

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like that:

```
DoStuff(pList.Concat(new[]{ new Parameter("@d", "dddd!"), new Parameter("@e", "eeee!"}).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `params` keyword requires an array as parameter type, and you could use `DoStuff(pList.ToArray());` then.

The definition you specified though should then be

```
public static DoStuff(params Parameter[] p){ /* ... */ }
```

Or have I missed out on some new features?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it's Parameter[] - I changed my original solution to make it a little easier and forgot to add that. Changed it. Simply passing an array does not work though.

Comment: It should work, try creating your own method `Test(params myType[] p)` and call `Test(new List<myType>() { ... }.ToArray())` - is the error message a compiler error or runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, why do you need to use the Iterate / yield method?

Is there a reason why this would not work?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Parameter> pList = new List<Parameter>();
    pList.Add(new Parameter("@a", "aaaa!"));
    pList.Add(new Parameter("@b", "bbbb!"));
    pList.Add(new Parameter("@c", "cccc!"));
    DoStuff(pList.ToArray());
}

static void DoStuff(params Parameter[] parameters){ 

    foreach(var p in parameters)
    {
        //do something.
    }

}
```

Comment: Does DoStuff(..) have two overloads? One for the Parameter array, and one for the Parameter Array plus single Parameter?